# filter based on condition met in another column

Tags: r, filter

I want to filter rows of a data frame based on the last date for a specific 'name'.

```
name  date
a     2021-06-30
a     2021-07-01
a     2021-07-02
b     2021-06-29
b     2021-06-30
c     2021-07-02
c     2021-07-03
```

```
name date
a    2021-07-02
b    2021-06-30
c    2021-07-03
```

However the last date is showing as the absolute maximum of the date column with the code I have believe, rather than the last date based on the name column

```
    df <- as.data.frame(tbl(con,"SQL Table"))
    last <- df %>%
      group_by(name) %>%
      summarize(date = max(date))
    name <- last$name
    end <- last$date

df <- filter(df, name == name & date == end)
```

The above results in this

```
name date
a    2021-07-03
b    2021-07-03
c    2021-07-03
```

Comment: Doesn't `last` have your expected output already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `last`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(date = last(date))
```

Output:

```
  name  date      
* <chr> <chr>     
1 a     2021-07-02
2 b     2021-06-30
3 c     2021-07-03
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `slice_tail`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(name) %>% 
    slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name  date      
  <chr> <date>    
1 a     2021-07-02
2 b     2021-06-30
3 c     2021-07-03
```

---

Or with `slice_max`

```
df %>%
     group_by(name) %>%
     slice_max(n = 1, order_by = 'date') %>%
     ungroup
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
 date = structure(c(18808, 
18809, 18810, 18807, 18808, 18810, 18811), class = "Date")), 
row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```